# Creating a new data frame in R from an exisiting, inadequate data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

This is a really simple problem, but I cannot figure out how to script it. I cannot move forward until I figure it out.  I'm really new to R and to using code, and I'm going through several introductory manuals, but haven't found anything for this specific problem yet.

Generally, here is the issue. Let's say I have a data frame called `x` that looks like:

```
a <- c(1995,1995,1995,1996,1997,1997,1997,1998)
b <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1)
c <- c(5,7,8,2,4,5,7,8)
(x <- data.frame(a,b,c))
     a b c
1 1995 1 5
2 1995 2 7
3 1995 3 9
4 1996 1 2
5 1997 2 4
6 1997 3 5
7 1997 4 7
8 1998 1 8
```

There are multiple entries for some of the years in column `a` (i.e. 1995 appears 3 times), when really I just want one entry for each year.  If I try to plot column `a` against column `c`, I will end up with multiple points for each date, but that is not helpful.  I don't care about column b, but **I want to sum entries for column `c` for each year, such that I end up with a data frame with one entry for each year**.  Given the above data, a resulting data frame would look like:

```
     a  c
1 1995 21
2 1996  2
3 1997 16
4 1998  8
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Tip: avoid calling things `c`. Remember that `c` is a function for creating vectors.

Comment: @csgillespie: That's true for objects.  It's not as big an issue for column names.

Comment: @Joshua: True, but (some people) may be tempted to do `c = df$c` without thinking.

Comment: Having a `c` object in the global environment doesn't mask the `c` function in the base package, so it's not actually a problem.  It could be confusing, though, so is best avoided, as @csgillespie suggests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`plyr`](http://had.co.nz/plyr/) library is useful for aggregation tasks such as these. `plyr` also plays very well with `ggplot2` graphics. In my opinion, the benefit of plyr is that you explicitly define the structure of the input and output. Here we are passing in a `data.frame` object and  also want a `data.frame` after processing, so we will use `ddply`. The first letter corresponds to the input object, and the second to the output. So if we wanted to go from a `list` object to `data.frame`, we'd use `ldply`, etc.

```
library(ggplot2) #Loads plyr

text <- "a b c
1995 1 5
1995 2 7
1995 3 9
1996 1 2
1997 2 4
1997 3 5
1997 4 7
1998 1 8
"

df <- read.table(textConnection(text), header = TRUE)

#Create plotData data.frame that groups by the "a" column and returns the sum of "c"
plotData <- ddply(df, "a", summarise, totalc = sum(c))

#plotting with ggplot
qplot(factor(a), totalc, data = plotData)
```

Comment: If I were a betting man, I would have put money on the `plyr` answer being accepted as the best.

Answer (score 9):

```
aggregate(x[,"c",drop=FALSE], by=x[,"a",drop=FALSE], sum)
```

The `drop=FALSE` is to ensure the object created by subsetting `x` is a data.frame.  If you omit `drop=FALSE` the dimensions of the data.frame will dropped (because you're only accessing one column of the data.frame) and the result of subsetting will be a vector.  See `?"["` and `?drop` for more details.

UPDATE: I agree with Gavin that the formula interface is cleaner:

```
aggregate(c ~ a, data=x, sum)
```

Comment: wouldn't it be just be easier to use the formula interface in this case? `aggregate(c ~ a, data = x, sum)` Also, you only need the `drop` on the `by` version as this argument takes a list only, for example this works just fine also: `aggregate(x[,"c2"], by = list(Year = x[,"c1"]), sum)`

Comment: @Gavin: very good point about the formula interface.  The reason I used `drop` on the first argument is so the column name would persist through to the new object.

Comment: good retort - touché - hadn't noticed that the name was preserved if the first argument is a data frame. +1.

Answer (score 9):

You need `tapply`. For example,

```
## Your data
c1 = c(1995, 1995, 1995, 1996, 1997,  1997, 1997, 1998) 
c2 = c(5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8)
x = data.frame(c1, c2)


y = tapply(x$c2, x$c1, sum)
names(y) ## For the years
as.vector(y)

## So to get a data frame
data.frame(a=names(y), c=as.vector(y))
```

Comment: Nice answer, but you need another step to convert `y` into a data.frame with columns "a" and "c".

Comment: @Joshua: I've added that step to the answer in case it wasn't clear. I can't really make my mind up about which answer I prefer - yours or mine.